# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes with screen distortion

Tags: 16.04, graphics, freeze, visual-artifacts

I am experiencing frequent freezes on my Ubuntu 16.04, but I cannot pinpoint the cause. It happens usually when I am sitting on the computer and not when it's idle, so it must be related to an action that I am doing at that time, but it seems to happen for no apparent reason.

I think that this issue might be related to my graphics drivers, because when it occurs my screens become distorted (with grey vertical stripes - looks nothing like the screen I had before the freeze). Sound repeats continuously when this happens. Additionally, my system becomes completely unresponsive and I can't even <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrScrn</kbd>+<kbd>REISUB</kbd> it – sometimes even the hard reset button doesn't work.

I searched stackoverflow for similar issues and it was suggested that this might be related to grub, so I applied the `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` fix; unfortunately it didn't work.

I also have `radeon.dpm=0` kernel setting in my grub config, because after a kernel update (~6+ months back) my screens were completely black and this seemed to fix my issue. I don't think that it's related to the issue I'm experiencing now.

Edit 1: The suggested solution would not solve my problem. I checked my packages and they are not yet updated to the following that cause the issue.

```
libegl1-mesa 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
libgbm1 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
libgl1-mesa-dri 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
libwayland-egl1-mesa 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
```

Edit 2: I was referring to the first linked solution. Sorry for missing the second one, when on the edit screen you can't see linked solutions. So on to what I've done, I fired up my terminal and did a:

```
❯ for p in libegl1 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libwayland-egl1-mesa ; do dpkg -l | grep $p | awk '{print $2, $3}' ; done 
libegl1-mesa:amd64 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
libgbm1:amd64 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

As you can see, my installed packages are all 12.0.6 and NOT 17.2.4 which cause the issue in the [GUI/Unity crashing in 16.04 LTS after updates 2018-01-04, compiz segfaults](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-updates-2018-01-04-compiz-segfaults).

As for [Ubuntu 14.04 has visual artifacts and freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612855/ubuntu-14-04-has-visual-artifacts-and-freezes), first of all the description is a lot like my problem, however:

- I am not getting video RAM artifacts. Everything is fine, up until the freeze. I will take a picture the next time I get a freeze, because it is hard to describe; it looks nothing like the previous screen I was displaying and it is usually a motiff of vertical grey stripes, something like [this one](https://images0.pixlis.com/background-image-vertical-lines-and-stripes-seamless-tileable-white-grey-22ra8w.png). After the restart I get no system problem detected, nor I get artifacts. I've extensively tried to pinpoint the problem by grepping `/var/log` before the moment of the freeze, however it is weirdly silent.
- My machine is a dual boot with windows 10, an operating system that I use mostly for gaming. As it is suggested in the linked answer, if this problem was caused due to a hardware error, I'd be getting similar behaviour (or at least restarts, freezes, blue screens, etc) in windows, too. However, I don't, which leads me to believe that the cause lies in the software.

The command that it is suggested I should run for the proprietary drivers and its output:

```
❯ ubuntu-drivers devices
== cpu-microcode.py ==
driver   : intel-microcode - distro free
```

more hardware details:

```
❯ sudo lshw -c video 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Juniper XT [Radeon HD 5770]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:25 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fbfc0000-fbfdffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fbfa0000-fbfbffff

❯ uname -a 
Linux apparatus 4.4.0-109-generic #132-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 19:52:39 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Update: I just had a freeze, but the system came back almost immediately (after 1-2 seconds) by itself (I was AFK, so I didn't reset it, touch it, or did anything to it). I noticed that it froze because music was playing on youtube.

I immediately sat down at checked /var/log for updated logfiles. I've got the following two that were updated at the time of the freeze:

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm       892624 Feb  3 18:21 kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm        29470 Feb  3 18:21 syslog
```

and their content:

```
/var/log
❯ tail -n 10  kern.log
Feb  3 15:34:32 apparatus kernel: [ 3682.917955] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.2/2-1.2.2:1.0/0003:046D:C077.0008/input/input21
Feb  3 15:34:32 apparatus kernel: [ 3682.918115] hid-generic 0003:046D:C077.0008: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2.2/input0
Feb  3 15:39:54 apparatus kernel: [ 4005.321271] perf: interrupt took too long (3920 > 3912), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 51000
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus kernel: [13672.371035] clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU1: Marking clocksource 'tsc' as unstable because the skew is too large:
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus kernel: [13672.371045] clocksource:                       'acpi_pm' wd_now: 9fec9b wd_last: e2aeff mask: ffffff
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus kernel: [13672.371048] clocksource:                       'tsc' cs_now: 213bf758e258 cs_last: 2139d0a0958a mask: ffffffffffffffff
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus kernel: [13672.371051] tsc: Marking TSC unstable due to clocksource watchdog
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus kernel: [13672.372782] TSC found unstable after boot, most likely due to broken BIOS. Use 'tsc=unstable'.
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus kernel: [13672.372785] sched_clock: Marking unstable (13671910344755, 462317015)<-(13672496000909, -123220420)
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus kernel: [13672.377012] clocksource: Switched to clocksource acpi_pm
```

and

```
/var/log
❯ tail -n 200 syslog
...
Feb  3 17:55:01 apparatus CRON[13191]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb  3 18:05:01 apparatus CRON[13508]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb  3 18:15:01 apparatus CRON[13819]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb  3 18:17:01 apparatus CRON[13898]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus kernel: [13672.371035] clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU1: Marking clocksource 'tsc' as unstable because the skew is too large:
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus kernel: [13672.371045] clocksource:                       'acpi_pm' wd_now: 9fec9b wd_last: e2aeff mask: ffffff
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus kernel: [13672.371048] clocksource:                       'tsc' cs_now: 213bf758e258 cs_last: 2139d0a0958a mask: ffffffffffffffff
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus kernel: [13672.371051] tsc: Marking TSC unstable due to clocksource watchdog
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus kernel: [13672.372782] TSC found unstable after boot, most likely due to broken BIOS. Use 'tsc=unstable'.
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus kernel: [13672.372785] sched_clock: Marking unstable (13671910344755, 462317015)<-(13672496000909, -123220420)
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_avail() returned a value that is exceptionally large: 654084 bytes (3707 ms).
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_dump():
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: Soft volume PCM
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: Control: PCM Playback Volume
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: min_dB: -51
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: max_dB: 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: resolution: 256
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stream       : PLAYBACK
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 16384
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 8192
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 185759
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 16129
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 4611686018427387904
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 4611686018427387904
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: Slave: Hardware PCM card 0 'HDA Intel MID' device 0 subdevice 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus kernel: [13672.377012] clocksource: Switched to clocksource acpi_pm
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stream       : PLAYBACK
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 16384
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 8192
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 185759
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 16129
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 4611686018427387904
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 4611686018427387904
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   appl_ptr     : 331041089
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   hw_ptr       : 331188226
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_delay() returned a value that is exceptionally large: -547748 bytes (-3105 ms).
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: snd_pcm_dump():
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: Soft volume PCM
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: Control: PCM Playback Volume
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: min_dB: -51
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: max_dB: 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: resolution: 256
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stream       : PLAYBACK
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 16384
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 8192
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 185759
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 16129
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 4611686018427387904
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 4611686018427387904
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: Slave: Hardware PCM card 0 'HDA Intel MID' device 0 subdevice 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c: Its setup is:
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stream       : PLAYBACK
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   format       : S16_LE
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   subformat    : STD
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   channels     : 2
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   rate         : 44100
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   msbits       : 16
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   buffer_size  : 16384
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_size  : 8192
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_time  : 185759
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_step  : 1
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   avail_min    : 16129
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   period_event : 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   start_threshold  : -1
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   stop_threshold   : 4611686018427387904
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_threshold: 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   silence_size : 0
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   boundary     : 4611686018427387904
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   appl_ptr     : 331051329
Feb  3 18:21:01 apparatus pulseaudio[4553]: [alsa-sink-ALC888 Analog] alsa-util.c:   hw_ptr       : 331188266
```