# Black pixel artifacts on all screens and freezing

Tags: freeze, gpu, visual-artifacts

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a computer I had laying around. I've had problems with it freezing. Everything freezes, but I can still move my mouse. How do I fix this?

[image]

What is it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04 has visual artifacts and freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612855/ubuntu-14-04-has-visual-artifacts-and-freezes)

Comment: Too early to close this question as a duplicate of a n issue with Ubuntu 14.04! At OP, obviously report system specifications and details, i.e., does if freeze immediately or after a while, or after you do something, etc.

Comment: I'm going to assume that you have shared video memory, and that the freezing and video artifacts are related to a memory problem. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.