# Graphics issues with ubuntu

Tags: graphics, freeze, nvidia-geforce, visual-artifacts

I just installed Ubuntu on an older computer. The graphics freeze and are skewed diagonally. I am running an Nvidia GeForce 7025 graphics card and was wondering what to do to correct this.

Comment: Try Lubuntu or Xubuntu instead. The standard Ubuntu with Gnome is simply too much for hardware of that vintage.

Comment: You should be specific; what do you classify as old?  I'm using a 2009 dell workstation & rarely consider it old as it works perfectly. Is old 2004? 2005? or when?  What architecture?  What release did you try and install?  What ISO & options did you install with ?  (ie. an ISO that contains 3rd party drivers, or not - did you try adding any?)  Which kernel stack did you opt to use? have you tried the alternate stack?  (eg. in QA-testing August-2020 I found some old (2004-2005 era) boxes didn't like the HWE kernel so the fix for them was sticking with GA for that release but you're using ???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04 has visual artifacts and freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612855/ubuntu-14-04-has-visual-artifacts-and-freezes)