# Ubuntu freezes with pixel flaws

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, freeze

Since Monday, my computer has started freezing randomly. It starts to show little squares of pixel flaws all over the screen. Sometimes I can still move the mouse and sometimes not, but it never responds anyways.

I have Ubuntu 20.04, AMD Ryzen 5600X, 32GB of RAM, and an Nvidia GTX 770. Also, I have an AOC screen (4k).

I am using REISUB to restart anytime, but I want to know what is happening. I have also checked other similar questions but I can't find anything yet.

Also, I have a dual boot with windows 10, and in this case, it shows a blue screen with a failure: DRIVER IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL (Fail was at `nvlddmkm.sys`).

This shows it could be a hardware problem, but for the moment I haven't found anything to finally check it. I have monitored both in Ubuntu and Windows and everything seems correct. Also cleaned the dust, changed from DisplayPort to HDMI, checked for driver updates, and checked the logs to see any relevant information but I'm still blinded.

Here are the logs from the last freeze:

```
Mar 1 12:02:18 giovanni-MS-7C37 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Mar 1 12:02:18 giovanni-MS-7C37 systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Succeeded.
Mar 1 12:02:18 giovanni-MS-7C37 systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Mar 1 12:02:26 giovanni-MS-7C37 gnome-shell[3177]: Error in cpuinfo: failed to parse processor information from /proc/cpuinfo
Mar 1 12:03:26 giovanni-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 1001.475775] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:2d:00: GPU-86d53ece-4553-0cf2-d276-5f9570f5a06c
Mar 1 12:03:26 giovanni-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 1001.475781] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:2d:00): 62, pid=1269, 0c83(1800) 00000000 00000000
Mar 1 12:03:49 giovanni-MS-7C37 pulseaudio[2671]: ALSA has sent a notification to write new data to the device, but there was actually nothing to write.
Mar 1 12:03:49 giovanni-MS-7C37 pulseaudio[2671]: This is probably an error in the ALSA driver "snd_usb_audio". Report the problem to the ALSA developers.
Mar 1 12:03:49 giovanni-MS-7C37 pulseaudio[2671]: The POLLOUT event has been set, however a subsequent snd_pcm_avail() has returned 0 or another value < min_avail.
```

I have searched for information about these logs and everything, but I haven't found anything relevant yet. Is it definitely a graphic card problem or is it something else? Is there anything I can do to fix it that doesn't involve changing the card? Thank you very much.

PS: To finish, I haven't really used a lot of the graphic cards or the PC lately. The most stressful situation has been playing Football Manager 2020 and it runs perfectly.

Edit: I am adding the output of commands suggested by Pilot6 in the comments

`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
2d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 770] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GK104 [GeForce GTX 770]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Also, yesterday I ran some tests to verify my hardware. Some coworkers pointed me that it could be a memory problem instead of a GPU, so I ran `memtest86`, I also ran tests for the hard drive and, of course for the GPU (I used OCCT in Windows). Everything was fine.

Update: I have followed this
but still getting this errors -> [Ubuntu 14.04 has visual artifacts and freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612855/ubuntu-14-04-has-visual-artifacts-and-freezes) (I haven't tried the graphic cards switching as I don't have another and a new one is expensive, so I rather buy when I know that this is the problem)

Also, I have disallowed GPU acceleration on Google Chrome and now, I am also having green screens on Ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04 has visual artifacts and freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612855/ubuntu-14-04-has-visual-artifacts-and-freezes)

Comment: I have already checked the drivers, although I don't think this could be the problem as I'm also having problems in Windows. The VRAM seems more like it's the problem, but yesterday I already used OCCT to test it. It was for one hour, so maybe I should test it longer just in case? I will try to disable GPU in Chrome in the meantime, as I don't have another graphic card and my CPU doesn't have an integrated one.