# Legion 5 Y9000P IAH7H - Freeze randomly on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, freeze

I have Legion 5 Y9000P IAH7H (GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q]) with Ubuntu on top of it. So I get freezes randomly, sometime ago it was only during google meet, but now it can be any time. By the type of freeze it looks like graphic card related. I've tried to reinstall nvidia drivers for all available version from 470 to 535 but this does not help. Also I've tried to use `sudo prime-select nvidia` but it does not help either.[image]

Comment: @karel sorry, but no.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04 has visual artifacts and freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612855/ubuntu-14-04-has-visual-artifacts-and-freezes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a RAM bug, but my video card gets some RAM to use it and then it occur bad memory cell. that it. btw, I've found a solution via vulkan mem test

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with freezes on my Legion Pro 5 16ARX8 82WM (R9000P) running Linux in hybrid graphics mode (amdgpu + nvidia 550 drivers).
And looks like i found a **workaround**.
The **nvidia GPU** can be in different states - **D3cold**, **D0**, **D3hot**.
I randomly noticed, that if I keep the **nvidia GPU** in **D0** state (just by opening the **nvidia-settings** panel at the **PowerMizer** tab) - freezes/stutters gone.

But if i let the **nvidia GPU** go into sleep mode (**D3cold** state) - freezes apperas every 2 min.
And *syslog* spammed by:

```
...
Feb 17 15:55:17 smarttop kernel: [ 9145.605086] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller  
Feb 17 15:57:17 smarttop kernel: [ 9265.612997] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller  
Feb 17 15:58:58 smarttop kernel: [ 9366.357103] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller  
Feb 18 00:30:06 smarttop kernel: [37914.905083] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
...
```

So it looks like the freezes was related to the nvidia HDA controller.
Also, just in case, I added `rmmod tpm` in GRUB menuentry.