# Glitches and freeze on Ubuntu 23.04 with AMD CPU

Tags: video, freeze

I've got a big problem on Ubuntu 23.04. I think could be a problem with graphic drivers, I randomly get glitches then laptop freeze and become unusable. It happen really often, about 4-5 minutes.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04 has visual artifacts and freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612855/ubuntu-14-04-has-visual-artifacts-and-freezes)